# Draw blinking circle inside a winforms panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

In the project i'm working, i need to draw a circle inside a panel and make it blinks. I've already made the circle drawing on the Paint event of a PictureBox, but i can't make it blinks. If possible, provide a solution without using timer.

The painting is trigger by the TextChanged event of opclblEventoCalidad, using this.pboxMaquina.Invalidate().

```
private async void opclblEventoCalidad_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CodigoMaquina))
         {
             _continueBlink = true;
             Alarmas = _maquinaContract.ObtenerAlarmas();
             string text = (sender as OPCControls.OPCControlsLabel).Text;
             if (Alarmas != null && Alarmas.Any(m => m.CodigoMaquina == this.CodigoMaquina))
             {
                 ColorInspeccion = Alarmas.First(s => s.CodigoMaquina == CodigoMaquina).CodigoColor;
                 CantidadInspecciones = Alarmas.First(s => s.CodigoMaquina == CodigoMaquina).CantidadInspecciones;
                 this.pboxMaquina.Invalidate();                  
             }
         }
     });
}

private void pboxMaquina_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GraficarAlarmasInspeccion(e);
}


private void GraficarAlarmasInspeccion(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    int rectangleWidth = Math.Min(pnlMaquina.Width, pnlMaquina.Height);
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(rectangleWidth / 2.75);
    int positionX = (pnlMaquina.Width - width) / 2;
    int positionY = (pnlMaquina.Height - width) / 2;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(positionX, positionY, width, width);

    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, rect);
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, rect);

    SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(this.CantidadInspecciones.ToString(), Font);
    PointF locationToDraw = new PointF();
    locationToDraw.X = (pnlMaquina.Width / 2);
    locationToDraw.Y = (pnlMaquina.Height / 2);
    StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
    using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", (float)(width / 2), FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.CantidadInspecciones.ToString(), myFont, Brushes.Black, locationToDraw, fmt);
    }
}
```

This produce the following image. Now i need to make this circle blink. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: timer event.  draw color, repaint, draw background, wax on wax off.

Comment: @DaveS, Thanks for helping, did exactly what you suggest and works like a charm!.